# Python script works locally but not through SSH

Tags: python, ssh, ros

I’m trying to link a Raspberry pi with pycroft with a Turtlebot via SSH. I have created a skill and I want that when I said “go to somewhere” the turtlebot goes to this place.

No problem with this part. The problem come here.

I have a python script and it works fine if firstly I connect via ssh and then I execute python go_to_specific_point_on_map.py

```
$ ssh tb2@192.168.0.158
$ python go_to_specific_point_on_map.py
```

[Image of everything working fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnTZh.png)

But if I tried to do all in one command, I get:
ImportError: No module named ‘rospy’

```
$ ssh tb2@192.168.0.158 python go_to_specific_point_on_map.py
```

[Image of the error. ImportError: No module named rospy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w39Hb.png)

```
^[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mubita/go_to_specific_point_on_map.py", line 22, in <module>
    import rospy
ImportError: No module named rospy
```

I have tried the arunp9294's solution but I get the same error.
    $ ssh tb2@192.168.0.158 "source ~/.bashrc; python go_to_specific_point_on_map.py"

The file go_to_specific_point_on_map.py is here:
[go to specific point on map script](https://github.com/markwsilliman/turtlebot/blob/master/go_to_specific_point_on_map.py)

I think it is a problem due to .bashrc is not loaded and the alias neither. I don’t know exactily what the problem is and how to solve it.

Can somebody help me? please.

I don’t know how to get it to work.

Thank you very much and best regards

Comment: ssh tb2@192.168.0.158 "source ~/.bashrc; python go_to_specific_point_on_map.py"

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code from your script, and explain what happens when you run it. If you're getting an error message or an exception, include the exact text of the message.

Comment: I have tried what arunp9294 said but I get the same error

Comment: Does this work: `ssh tb2@192.168.0.158 "bash -i -c 'python go_to_specific_point_on_map.py'"`? Maybe `-i` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's a path problem, try adding the location of the rospy module to the pythonpath with:

```
import sys

sys.path.append("/path/to/rospy/in/your/turtlebot")

import rospy
```

the problem with this is that you have to manually change the path if the code is executed on different systems with different locations of the 'rospy' module

If you don't know the path you can first execute a python program like

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

in both ways (directly in the ssh, and after the ssh) and see if there is a difference in the output, if you see a difference just extend the path in your code with that difference.

example:

output with execution after connection:

```
$ ssh tb2@192.168.0.158
$ python print_path.py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

output with connection and execution in one command:

```
$ ssh tb2@192.168.0.158 python print_path.py
['a', 'b']
```

if you see a difference then modify the code in the turtlebot with:

```
import sys

sys.path.extend(['c', 'd'])

import rospy
...
```

Comment: I don't have install ROS in the Raspberry and neither rospy. I want to connect the Raspberry without ROS with a Turtlebot with ROS via SSH. In the Turtlebot I do have ROS installed. Indeed everything works fine when firstly I connect via SSH and then execute python go_to_specific_point_on_map.py. Thank you very much

Comment: sorry, i thought that the raspberry was the target of the connection.  I have updated the answer, check if it works

Comment: Sorry for not answering sooner. I tried what you said and I got another error. This time "module not found" with one module of ROS. I have spent one week trying to install ROS on the Pycroft installation but I got some errors. I solved one but I got a newer one. I came to the SSH method and your help. I have added the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to the ssh command and everything works great. Thank you very much @Hoxha Alban